# Unable to compile a4tech-bloody-linux-driver on Linux Mint 18, nor Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, cmake, g++, ubuntu-16.04

Since I bought A4Tech Bloody V8 mouse, I would like to install the driver for Linux, specifically for Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04 based).

I found this driver on GitHub:

https://github.com/maxmati/a4tech-bloody-linux-driver

---

Since there is no documentation as for how to install it, so far I figured out how to prepare it for compilation:

First I installed `cmake`:

```
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Then I prepared it for `make` as follows:

```
cmake .
```

I attach the output for future reference, but I don't see any error there:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/vlastimil/Downloads/a4tech-bloody-linux-driver-master
```

---

I have tried to do all of the steps suggested on this issue page: https://github.com/maxmati/a4tech-bloody-linux-driver/issues/10

But when running this:

```
rm CMakeCache.txt && cmake . && make clean && make
```

I get these errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target bloody
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable bloody
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::init()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `libusb_init'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::discoverDevices()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `libusb_open'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `libusb_close'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_address'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::~Mouse()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `libusb_close'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x391): undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::writeToMouse(unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::readFromMouse(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::listDevices()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x6c6): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'bloody' failed
make[2]: *** [bloody] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/bloody.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

```
locate libusb.h
```

tells me, that it exists in:

```
/usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
```

but trying to manually compile it with `g++`:

```
g++ main.cpp -lusb-1.0
```

says, it did not find it:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
Mouse.h:8:20: fatal error: libusb.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Confusing.

---

List of files generated looks well:

```
ll

total 124K
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 6.3K Nov 17 15:25 build.make
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  276 Nov 17 15:25 cmake_clean.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  551 Nov 17 15:25 CXX.includecache
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  799 Nov 17 15:25 DependInfo.cmake
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  445 Nov 17 15:25 depend.internal
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  274 Nov 17 15:25 depend.make
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  255 Nov 17 15:25 flags.make
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  182 Nov 17 15:25 link.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil 9.9K Nov 17 15:25 main.cpp.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil  69K Nov 17 15:25 Mouse.cpp.o
-rw-r--r-- 1 vlastimil vlastimil   64 Nov 17 15:25 progress.make
```

I am just unable to link them together into a binary file, I tried it directly:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/include/libusb-1.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lusb-1.0 main.cpp.o Mouse.cpp.o -o bloody

Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::init()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `libusb_init'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `libusb_set_debug'
Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::discoverDevices()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_list'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x10a): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x14c): undefined reference to `libusb_open'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `libusb_kernel_driver_active'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `libusb_detach_kernel_driver'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x1a6): undefined reference to `libusb_close'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x1cc): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_address'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `libusb_free_device_list'
Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::~Mouse()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `libusb_close'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x391): undefined reference to `libusb_exit'
Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::writeToMouse(unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x497): undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::readFromMouse(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long)':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `libusb_control_transfer'
Mouse.cpp.o: In function `Mouse::listDevices()':
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device'
Mouse.cpp:(.text+0x6c6): undefined reference to `libusb_get_device_descriptor'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

I am wondering if it could be the linker's error (?)

---

The last idea I had was to link those two object files together:

```
g++ -o output main.cpp.o Mouse.cpp.o
```

But that ended up the same as above direct attempt.

---

Compiler version is:

```
g++-5.real (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

---

I don't know how to proceed further. Thank you for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had I lot of trouble with this, but eventually I figured it out.

There may be better solutions, and if so, please add yours.

Copy this file, for whatever reason not found by the linker to the compiling folder:

```
cp /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h ./
```

And manualy invoke compiling:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp Mouse.cpp -I. -L. -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -lusb-1.0 -o "mouse-set-backlight"
```

This will create `mouse-set-backlight` file, which at this very moment does not recognize my mouse. That I will try to resolve tomorrow.

---

Fix for Bloody V8 Core 2:

Edit this file:

```
Mouse.h
```

Change this line:

```
static const int BLOODY_V8_PID = 0x11F5;
```

to:

```
static const int BLOODY_V8_PID = 0x36E1;
```

And compile again.

---

How to fix unknown versions of your Bloody mouse, generally:

```
dmesg | grep Mouse
```

the output should look somewhat like mine:

```
[462227.138026] hid-generic 0003:09DA:36E1.0005: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [COMPANY USB Device] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input1
```

Look into this part:

```
hid-generic 0003:09DA:36E1.0005
```

where the third part of the address, in my case `36E1` that is, is what you need.

Add `0x` prefix to it, i.e. `0x36E1`

Finally, edit your `Mouse.h` similarly to how I did it above.

And compile again.